# Why am I not warned of too large numbers in C# (and other questions)?

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# by myself, and am solving project Euler problems to practice. I've written the code below that solves [problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8), which asks to find the largest product of 13 consecutive digits in a long sequence of digits. I read this sequence of digits into the program from a file.

First, I started out by defining the numeric variables "maxProduct" and "productTmp" as having type "int", but I didn't get the right answer, because it's larger than the maximal range of this type. What confuses me is that I didn't get an error, or a warning, saying that I tried to manipulate too large numbers when I was dealing with my ints. Instead, it seemed to "wrap around" its range, which seems useless. Is this how it's supposed to be?

Second, the part where it reads a file is something I found online. For some reason, however, I can't write just "IO.StreamReader", but I have to include "System." in front of it, even though I have included the "using System;" line. I thought the using statement made everything contained in "System" available for reference without the System.-prefix.

And third, in the while loop where it reads in the file, what is going on? My guess is that (line = file.ReadLine()) is a Boolean statement, but in that case, it doesn't make sense that it can be equal to null. Also, I haven't given "line" a value, so that statement looks like it compares a null value of line to something else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace problem8
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int noAdjacentDigits = 13;

        long maxProduct = 0;
        string numberSequence = "", line;


        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:/problem8.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            numberSequence = numberSequence + line;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberSequence.Length-noAdjacentDigits;i++)
        {
            string substrTmp = numberSequence.Substring(i, noAdjacentDigits);
            long productTmp = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= noAdjacentDigits-1; j++)
            {
                productTmp = productTmp * int.Parse(substrTmp.Substring(j,1));
            }
            if (productTmp > maxProduct) maxProduct = productTmp;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(maxProduct);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Another possible way to handle your overflow problem is to look at the ratio between consecutive 13 digit products. Do this by finding the ratios of digits that are 13 apart in the input sequence. For instance, if the 14th digit is larger than the first digit, then you know that the product of the 2nd through 14th digits are greater than the product of digits 1 through 13

Comment: Your question covers three unrelated subjects, which is too broad. Please stick to one subject per question.

Comment: @EBrown no, it says I'm missing an "assembly reference". I suppose that BigInteger is useful, when you don't know beforehand what the size of your integers are? But it also sounds like something that isn't good on the performance side.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter good insight. Thanks. Your solution will also boil down the number of operations to about 1/13th.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Instead, it seemed to "wrap around" its range, which seems useless. Is this how it's supposed to be?

Yes, unless you put the math in a `checked` block or use the `/checked` compiler option.  The decision is mostly for performance reasons, since overflow checking takes time and is usually not necessary.

> I can't write just `IO.StreamReader`, but I have to include `System.` in front of it

You can't start a declaration in the middle of a namespace.  Add `Using System.IO` to the top and you can just type `StreamReader`.

> My guess is that (line = file.ReadLine()) is a Boolean statement

No, `ReadLine` returns a string, which is `null` if the end of file has been reached.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) is fairly clear:

> Reads a line of characters from the current stream and returns the data as a string.
>
> ...
>
> The returned value is `null` if the end of the input stream is reached.

Comment: For completeness: you can start a reference to a type in the middle of a namespace, if you're referring to a namespace that's nested in the current namespace. Example: `namespace N1 { class C1 { public static N2.C2 f() { return null; } } namespace N2 { class C2 { } } }`.

Comment: For even more completenes: The condition to test for equality is written as `==` : `if (sum  == 10)..`

Comment: @hvd what do you mean starting a reference to a "type"? I thought types were ints, strings, etc. I thought that <code>"IO"</code> was another namespace that contains the StreamReader class. Also, I had the impression that the dot separating namespaces, e.g. <code>System.IO</code>, signified that "IO" was a namespace contained in the namespace "System", so that "IO" was nested inside of "System". (Also, why won't my code-tags work?)

Comment: @HowDoICSharp use back-ticks (`  `) to delimit code blocks within comments.

Answer (score 1):

> For some reason, however, I can't write just "IO.StreamReader", but I have to include "System." in front of it, even though I have included the "using System;" line. I thought the using statement made everything contained in "System" available for reference without the System.-prefix.

All types in the `System` namespace will be made available by `using System;`, but `System.IO` is not a type, it's another namespace. You can write `using System.IO;`, though, and then use `StreamReader` directly.

> And third, in the while loop where it reads in the file, what is going on? My guess is that (line = file.ReadLine()) is a Boolean statement,

It's not. The result of an assignment is the value that was assigned. `(line = file.ReadLine()) != null` calls `file.ReadLine()`, assigns the result to `line`, and then checks whether the value that was assigned (the result of the function call) was `null`.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know you could assign things inside the while statement.

Answer (score 1):

Statements can execute in either [checked or unchecked contexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx).

> In a checked context, arithmetic overflow raises an exception. In an unchecked context, arithmetic overflow is ignored and the result is truncated.

C# language specification §7.6.12 states the following about *default behavior*:

> For non-constant expressions (expressions that are evaluated at run-time) that are not enclosed by any checked or unchecked operators or statements, **the default overflow checking context is unchecked** unless external factors (such as compiler switches and execution environment configuration) call for checked evaluation.